# Le « portage » et le « rétroportage » : s'agit-il de « porter » ; avec quelle préposition introduit-on la destination ?

Tags: prépositions, terminologie, informatique, compléments

On a le [*portage*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8385298) (angl. *porting*) et le [*retroportage*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9troportage) (angl. *backporting*) d'un logiciel (*Franceterme* a celui des [devises](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=portage%20de%20devises&francetermeSearchDomaine=0&francetermeSearchSubmit=rechercher&action=search)) :

> Adaptation d'un logiciel tournant dans un environnement informatique
>   donné dans le but de le transférer sur un ordinateur dont
>   l'environnement est différent.
>
> *GDT*, portage
>
> ---
>
> Le rétroportage, ou backporting en anglais, est l'action consistant à
>   aller piocher une modification développée pour une nouvelle version
>   d'un logiciel afin d'en faire bénéficier une version plus ancienne de
>   ce logiciel (au moyen d'un logiciel patch [[correctif]](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_(informatique))).
>
> *Wikipédia*, rétroportage

---

- Est-ce que ça signifie que le verbe *(rétro)[porter](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/porter)* est adéquat pour
  exprimer l'action dont il est question ici ? Pourquoi (pas) ?
- Quelle préposition introduit le complément désignant la (plateforme de)
  destination du logiciel ; y a-t-il préposition différente selon (la direction) qu'on dise *porter* ou *rétroporter* ?

  > J'ai (rétro)porté ce logiciel [à, pour, sur, vers, dans... auprès de ?]
  >   *AmigaOS*.
- Si on n'emploie pas le verbe *porter* pour *portage/rétroportage*, utilise-t-on le verbe *faire* en auxiliaire et utilise-t-on la même préposition ; qu'est-ce qui est le plus usuel ?

  > J'ai fait le rétroportage de ce logiciel [à, pour, sur, vers, dans... auprès de ?] *Gentoo Linux*.
- Dans l'usage au Canada, en ce qui a trait au [*portage*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/portage) d'une
  embarcation (canot, cayak), est-ce qu'on emploie *portager* avec les mêmes prépositions qu'avec ce qui précède (pour introduire la destination) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oui, le verbe porter est utilisé avec cette acception. La préposition usuelle semble être *sur*, par exemple :

> Porter un jeu PC **sur** Mac

On trouve aussi *vers* et *pour*.

Rétroporter est utilisé mais dans la plupart des usages que je trouve, la destination est implicitement dérivée du contexte, par exemple :

> J'ai passé 4 heures à rétroporter les correctifs. [Sous-entendu : sur la vieille version.]

On rencontre tout de même des prépositions *vers*, *sur* et *pour* occasionnellement.

Comment: Merci ! Dans votre premier exemple, si on avait un environnement de développement, ou un ensemble de librairies (donc un truc moins vaste que le système d'exploitation etc.), comme destination, ou que l'action visait une caractéristique particulière pour un même logiciel avec versions différentes, préfère-t-on toujours _sur_ ; en d'autres termes le _sur_ est-il tributaire de ce qu'on dit de manière usuelle avec l'OS (tourner sur ?) ou avec le verbe _porter_ pour l'action en question ?

Comment: @Faʁdɔʃɔtɔmatabaʁwɛt Je ne vois pas de différence...

Comment: @Random Donc vous diriez aussi _sur Cocoa_ ou _sur .Net_ ? N'hésitez pas à produire une réponse ! Merci.

Comment: @Faʁdɔʃɔtɔmatabaʁwɛt C'est compliqué... ce n'est pas un vocabulaire qu'on utilise tous les jours... Personnellement je n'ai jamais utilisé ces termes... mais .Net étant un framework, je dirais "j'ai porté l'application vers .Net". Mais pour un langage (comme par exemple PHP), je dirais "j'ai porté l'application en PHP"... Le choix entre "en" / "sur" et "vers" n'est pas facile...

Comment: @Random Il s'agit essentiellement d'adapter un logiciel. Le choix de préposition semble s'adapter à la géométrie de la destination (sur une plateforme, vers le large, en langage etc.), ou s'appuyer sur porter matériellement vers un lieu. D'où la suggestion de voir si _faire un rétroportage_ nous fait penser différemment; d'où celle de voir si _portager_ une embarcation diffère. Merci.

Comment: @Faʁdɔʃɔtɔmatabaʁwɛt J'ai un peu réfléchi à cette question avant de répondre. L'hypothèse selon laquelle la préposition dépend du type de destination (OS, bibliothèque, version...) est intéressante mais je n'ai pas trouvé de validation empirique. Par contre dans mon usage personnel, une considération importante est la facilité de lecture, notamment l'évitement d'ambiguïtés dans les formulations comme "porter ce jeu pour Mac" -- s'agit-il d'un "jeu pour Mac" que l'on souhaite porter (vers un autre os) ou d'un jeu que l'on souhaite porter sur Mac ?

Comment: Votre propos est bien intéressant, merci. Je retrouve moins, j'ai l'impression, cette ambiguïté dont vous parlez si je sélectionne le verbe _adapter_ plutôt que le verbe _porter_. On dirait que même si porter est utilisé dans l'acception dont on traite, il suit comme un prototype basé sur la matérialité de l'action (porter, transporter), et est peu cohérent avec _pour_. On dirait (encore l'hypothétique) que des génériques sous-jacents/périphrases dictent le choix de préposition. C'est la _greffe/transplantation_ ? Comp. en anglais _to port_ se comporte-t-il comme _carry_ ; _to_ or _over to_?

Comment: Je n'ai jamais entendu *rétroporter* mais j'utilise couramment l'anglicisme *backporter*. Par exemple *j'ai backporté le patch de la version 11 vers la version 10*